# How to mix two mp3 files in and generate one in iPhone app

Tags: iphone, audio

I have two mp3 files, a.mp3 of 5 seconds and b.mp3 of 7 seconds and I want to mix them in order to generate c.mp3 of duration 7 secs. 
I have tried the following code Example 4 of the following link
http://www.modejong.com/iOS/#ex4

but it mixes only caf files and I need to mix the MP3 files of different sizes.

Thanks-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here for your requirement you can use this bellow demo code with convert two `.mp3` or `caf` file to one file , see the tutorial and get some idea and also use these Demos ..

Please see this bellow links with sample codes and tutorials..

1. [AudioConverterFileConvert](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/iPhoneACFileConvertTest/Listings/AudioConverterFileConvert_cpp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010581-AudioConverterFileConvert_cpp-DontLinkElementID_3)
2. [iPhoneExtAudioFileConvertTest](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/iPhoneExtAudioFileConvertTest/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009222)

i hope this help you...

Comment: Thanks Paras for your answer. I will look into this and let you know the feedback.

Comment: The first code giving this error!
AudioSessionSetProperty kAudioSessionCategory_AudioProcessing failed! -50

Comment: Where is the link to tutorial?

Comment: just go through this link step by step http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/iPhoneACFileConvertTest/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010581-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2 and also use 2 option if its easy for u dude...

Comment: @Harsh also see this dude for Audiosession property.. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/AudioToolbox/Reference/AudioSessionServicesReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/econst/kAudioSessionProperty_OverrideCategoryMixWithOthers

Comment: I need your help to understand how can I mix 2 audio file using this code.

Comment: You can explain any of them which can work. Let me know if you need more explanation on my requirement!

Comment: No problem! Please send the explanation at harsh_mehrotra2000@yahoo.com and include your name in the Subject

Answer (score 3):

You need to use [AVMutableCompositionTrack](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVMutableCompositionTrack_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and [AVAssetExportSession Class](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAssetExportSession_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to do it.

Here is a sample code on [developer.Apple.com](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/MixerHost/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010210).

This is a nice [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/13418/how-to-play-record-edit-videos-in-ios) which merge two video files and one music file into a single file. This same code can be reused to merge two audio files.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I have already seen the Apple's Code and it plays two audio files parallely but doesn't mix them to create one single file. And I will look into the tutorial you have provided and get back to you. In the mean time can you please send me some sample code?